# d3.js map slave/master application

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, brush

I am struggling to stabilize this application. I am trying to create a brush (with a set height/width) on the mini map to control the large map. The latest working prototype is here.

http://jsfiddle.net/BxLHd/6/

inside the brush function I have found a way of maybe pulling out the right data, just not sure how to get the ratio/zoom correct for the maps and fix the height/width of the brush without making it buggy.

```
worldMap.classed("selected", function(d) {

    console.log("extent[0]", extent[0]);
    console.log("extent[1]", extent[1]);

    var boxWidth = extent[1][0] - extent[0][0];
    var boxHeight = extent[1][1] - extent[0][1];

    console.log("boxWidth", boxWidth);
    console.log("boxHeight", boxHeight);

    var smallMapWidth = 120;
    var smallMapHeight = 80;

    var bigMapWidth = 600;
    var bigMapHeight = 400;

    var xRatio = extent[0][0]/smallMapWidth;
    var yRatio = extent[1][1]/smallMapHeight;

    var newX =  bigMapWidth*xRatio;
    var newY =  bigMapHeight*yRatio;

    worldMapper.newT = new Array(newX, newY);
    worldMapper.newScale = 100;

    worldMapper.redraw()

})
```

Comment: Hello, I think you need to describe what is the design of the app, and everything will just flow from that. So, what is desired behavior of the brash, what should be displayed on the large map for given brush position, etc. Please tell that us here, we can't guess. Complete design of the app. It should not take more than few paragraphs. Otherwise, app looks attractive.

Comment: I have made this cut down version - that just includes the map. http://jsfiddle.net/BxLHd/8/ I am trying to create a fixed box/rectangular brush that can not be reshapped but repositioned on the small map. I want to have the brush on the small map control the larger map. However, I have not been able to gain complete control on the zoom level of the larger map, nor the correct ratio/pan view for the small map. Is anyone here able to view the code in version 8 and help me stabilize the brush/brush controls.

Comment: Any update on this? Where you able to achieve the desired result?